# UWP Windows 10 JS - background audio work when compile directly to my device, but not when opened from store

Tags: audio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, background-audio

Let describe my issue:

I have developed JS app for Windows 10. It works on desktop- background audio, title, album cover- all stuff i need. In VisualStudio- when i deploy app to Mobile Emulator (10.10586)- still- background audio works even if app is gone.
If i deploy my app through Visual Studio to my Mobile Device- everything works great (when it is run/deployed from visual studio). BUT (notice that) - if i open that compile app again from my device (later, i exit visual studio or just close the solution)- backrgound audio: didnt work.
Hope i describe it well- i deploy app, which work great when compile it first time, but lately... didnt.

So, i can provide my code if someone need to check out, but i think is something with platform... and i am not sure how to fix that and how to get help with that :/

Thank you!

Comment: Could you share a basic sample through online repository that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Thanks for response... Sure... i notice that this issue is somehow connected with suspend mode. But... still- why in W10 Desktop works, but not in mobile :/ and... other thing is that when app go in background mode/suspend - still in volume up/down player is showed stream from my app. 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ald8d6i3-I-Wj8k_ViLUGfQpPXnmEQ - is link to 7zip archive. If u can- take a look. Thanks in advance :)
May the force be with u!

Comment: Hmm, after some research... i am pretty sure it is not possible to do that only with javascript... or there is not example in that way. Always is included some C# class or something. However... thank u anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research i made... there is no chance to build and complete that only with javascript. For now... after Anniversary update (2016, August) there is a chance- [Microsoft employee](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/419) confirms that will be possible and we can explorer that with this example they provide: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/dev/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlayback ... so... will wait to see :)